# Django. Async database engine.

Tags: python, django, psycopg

Psycopg2 has async mode.

But if we will set `async=1` in OPTIONS for postgresql_psycopg2 - we will get error `commit cannot be used in asynchronous mode`.

So, is there any wrapper, like momoko, for django, that supports async mode?

Comment: Maybe start here: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#asynchronous-notifications